# Need a creative JavaScript "Hack" - Prepopulating Forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, greasemonkey, same-origin-policy

We have a new client at work that wants our call center to fill out applications on their website. We have all the data for the people calling into the call center and my boss wants me to make their application prepopulate with the name and other info from our database. Problem is their programmer is "under water" and at this time is not able or willing to change their form to help me out in any way.

I know plain old Javasccript can't do it (Same origin policy)..

But I have considered forcing everyone to use FireFox and writing a greasemonkey script.

I have also considered attempting to use PHP's cURL, but I'm not even sure that would work..

Both of those are really dirty solutions though.

Does any one have any creative solutions? I've been looking at this too long and could really use some outside input.

Thanks for looking

EDIT..

I should specify that we would be loading their application in a frame/iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script in JavaScript and then run it in Chrome with web security disabled:

http://davfxx.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-security-on-chrome/

You'll have to start Chrome from a terminal, but this can easily be explained in a brief set of instructions. In my experience, it is much easier to disable the same-origin policy on Chrome than on other browsers.